# LinkedIn: Find Profile by VanityName - Approved developer

Tags: api, video, linkedin-api, webhooks, profile

My team and I are looking to add to our app several features of the Linkedin API that are currently restricted. In order of importance to us:

- [Find Profile by VanityName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-vanity-name-api)
- Webhooks
- Video UGC Post

We already quite understand that Webhooks and Video UGC Post are REALLY restricted. What about the first one?

In general, how can we get in contact with the right people to get such approvals? Nowhere it is mentioned that we cannot apply, just that it is restricted.
We are very happy to work with Linkedin requirements, whatever they are.

Thanks.

Thibault Drevon,
CTO of bobcaat.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to find profile by VanityName with LinkedIn API you need to become a LinkedIn Partner.

First you need to create an application  https://www.linkedin.com/developer/apps

Once you've created an "application" you can then apply to become a LinkedIn partner. To apply go to https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs/apply

LinkedIn's Business Development team will review all applications and will endeavour to respond to you within 15 days.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comment.
This requirement is already satisfied on our side. We are Linkedin Marketing partners since several months but we don't have access to that feature and get following result:
`{'serviceErrorCode': 100, 'message': 'Not enough permissions to access: GET-vanityName /people', 'status': 403}` 

Hence my question: who to contact and what to do about this?

Our app is called "bobcaat" and belongs to Yellowstones.